# Jquery .each --- if the value not starts with 0

Tags: jquery, html

Am trying to fetch user entered values in UI using below code

```
$.each($('item'), function(i, v) {
  var test = new Object();
  test.attribute = $("#Attribute_" + i).val();
  test.operand = $("#Operand_" + i).val();
  test.value = $("#Value_" + i).val();
});
```

My HTML code

```
<div class="item">
    <input id="Attribute_0" name="Attribute_1" type="text">
    <select id="Operand_0">
    <input id="Value_0" type="text">
</div>

    <div class="item">
        <input id="Attribute_1" name="Attribute_1" type="text">
        <select id="Operand_1">
        <input id="Value_1" type="text">
    </div>
```

Everything Works Fine as long as my Id Starts with 0 `(Attribute_0,Operand_0).`

But if it starts with 1 or higher the above function is not working because .each i value starts with 0.

If HTML starts like

```
 <div class="item">
                <input id="Attribute_1" name="Attribute_1" type="text">
                <select id="Operand_1">
                <input id="Value_1" type="text">
            </div>
```

and am getting Null

There may be lot other ways to fetch values but currently i implemented this and want to stick to the same code with some modifications.

How do i handle this ?

Thanks

Comment: i wonder, how is this working.. since your item selector is incorrect...it should be.. `$.each($('.item'), function(i, v) {`..you missed the `.` operator there(Class selector)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your HTML to use classes instead of IDs:

```
<div class="item">
    <input class="attribute" name="Attribute_1" type="text">
    <select class="operand">
    <input class="value" type="text">
</div>
```

and then use the class selector + `.children` to get a reference to the element inside the current `.item`:

```
$('.item').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var test = {
    attribute: $this.children('.attribute').val(),
    operand: $this.children('.operand').val(),
    value = $this.children('.value').val()
  };
});
```

Alternatively, if the order of form element is always the same (attribute, operand, value), you can access the children by position (without using any class or ID):

```
$('.item').each(function() {
  var $children= $(this).children();
  var test = {
    attribute: $children.eq(0).val(),
    operand: $children.eq(1).val(),
    value = $children.eq(2).val()
  };
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick, if you're dead set against changing your markup. Check out the jQuery documentation for the ["Attribute Starts With" Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

```
$('.item').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this),
      test  = {
        attribute : $this.find('[id^="Attribute_"]').val(), 
        operand   : $this.find('[id^="Operand_"]').val(),
        value     : $this.find('[id^="Value_"]').val()
      };
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/umyXT/)

Comment: i think you missed `.` operator there in item selector.. :)

Comment: +1 Thanks @Cecchi. If i have 2 rows still test onlt returns the last row. Checked in ur Fiddle as well. It should return all rows right ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it two ways viz.

**Solution 1:**

```
test.attribute = $(this).find("input[id^='Attribute_']").val();
test.operand = $(this).find("select[id^='Operand_']").val();
test.value = $(this).find("input[id^='Value_']").val();
```

**Solution 2**
Assign a class to the Attribute,operand and value tag and target that contrl with below mentioned code:-

```
test.attribute = $(this).find(".AttributeTag]").val();
test.operand = $(this).find(".OperandTag").val();
test.value = $(this).find(".ValueTag]").val();
```

Hope this helps. Let me know if you want more clarification on this solution.